# angular-file-upload not adding file to the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angular-file-upload

I'm using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) to upload a picture to the server running Node and Express 4.0 and I'm having trouble getting to the file data on the erver.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
```

Angular controller:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {  
    var file = $files[0];

    // [..] validation

    $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'api/settings/picture',
        method: 'POST',
        file: file,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
      }).progress(function (evt) {
          $scope.percent = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      }).success(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }).error(function () {
          console.log('error');
      });
};
```

Server code:

```
// Picture
app.route('/api/settings/picture')
  .post(middleware.auth, users.changePicture);
```

Route handler:

```
exports.changePicture = function (req, res) {
  var userId = req.user._id;
  console.log(req.files);
};
```

`req.files` is always `undefined`

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by changes in Express 4.0.

I solved it using [Multer](https://github.com/hacksparrow/multer.).

More info on this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/INjdKyS3--0